# Get Search Results without user authentication

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, twitter

I am building a app for users who don't have Twitter, so user authentication is impossible. I got it working with the user timeline but not with search.

I got this error back from Twitter:

```
{"errors":[{"message":"Could not authenticate you","code":32}]}
```

Here is my code that works:

```
MKNetworkOperation *operation = [[MKNetworkOperation alloc] initWithURLString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json" params:[@{ @"screen_name" : user } mutableCopy] httpMethod:@"GET"];
    [operation addHeaders:@{ @"Authorization" : [self OAuthHeaderForURL:[NSURL URLWithString:operation.url]] }];
    [operation onCompletion:^(MKNetworkOperation *completedOperation) {
        completionBlock([completedOperation responseJSON]);
    } onError:^(NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"\n\n\nError bij User: %@", error);
    }];
    [self.networkEngine enqueueOperation:operation];
```

And this is the code with the problem:

```
MKNetworkOperation *operation = [[MKNetworkOperation alloc] initWithURLString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json" params:[@{ @"q" : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"#%@", hashtag] } mutableCopy] httpMethod:@"GET"];
    [operation addHeaders:@{ @"Authorization" : [self OAuthHeaderForURL:[NSURL URLWithString:operation.url]] }];
    [operation onCompletion:^(MKNetworkOperation *completedOperation) {
        completionBlock([completedOperation responseJSON]);
    } onError:^(NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"\n\n\nError bij Hashtag: %@", error);
    }];
    [self.networkEngine enqueueOperation:operation];
```

Here is the cURL command line string:

```
curl -X GET -H "Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="XizVPuR2LQcnL9xAzMo6AA", oauth_nonce="2806C6BC-5B67-42E4-BAC9-1D3F2D8A", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1371545629", oauth_version="1.0", oauth_token="74944468-tYmMuxMaaZUxiTHuZ78Y9qljCqCiPcfKvhavS9wuU", oauth_signature="6E1ggIZYIBrRQJ9i1LeqLQBM5fc%3D"" -H "Accept-Language: en, fr, de, ja, nl, it, es, pt, pt-PT, da, fi, nb, sv, ko, zh-Hans, zh-Hant, ru, pl, tr, uk, ar, hr, cs, el, he, ro, sk, th, id, ms, en-GB, ca, hu, vi, en-us" "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%23demeern"
```

If somebody could help me it would be great.

Comment: Authentication isn't impossible, you authenticate with some secret and private keys that **you** get from the twitter dev site. This authorises your application to make the requests you need (this requirement has *nothing* to do with your users).

Comment: Thanks for your help, could you say what I am doing wrong, I don't get why the user_timeline does works and the search doesn't, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The API which allow you to get search results without user authentication is Version 1.0 and it's displayed, so you need to authenticate your request with some twitter library, this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17207317/ios-how-to-fetch-tweet-from-twitter-api-1-1/17207745#17207745) will guide you how to do that and how to get a search result.