# Twitter api 1.1 oauth fails when searching hashtags

Tags: php, javascript, twitter

I'm using a modified php-script I found on the internet to function as a proxy between javascript and twitter api 1.1 (I need to do this because javascript can't do oauth operations and api 1.1 requires exactly that: authentication).

The script works fine - up until I search for a hashtag, then oauth fails.

Here's an example of the curl_info I get from twitter when searching for @z25org

```
url: http://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%40z25org
content_type: application/json;charset=utf-8
http_code: 200
```

As you can see this works (http_code: 200). But when I search for a hashtag:

```
url: http://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%23z25org
content_type: application/json; charset=utf-8
http_code: 401
```

I get http_code 401: Unauthorized access. The json:

```
{"errors":[{"message":"Could not authenticate you","code":32}]}
```

Here's my php code: (well, the biggest part of it)

```
<?php
// Some characters that need to be replaced
$specialCharacters = array(
    "@"=>"%40",
    "#"=>"%23",
    " "=>"%20",
    ""=>""
);

/*
* Ok, no more config should really be needed. Yay!
*/

// We'll get the URL from $_GET[]. Make sure the url is url encoded, for example encodeURIComponent('statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=MikeRogers0&count=10&include_rts=false&exclude_replies=true')
if(!isset($_GET['url'])){
    die('No URL set');
}

$url = $_GET['url'];

// Figure out the URL parmaters
$url_parts = parse_url($url);
parse_str($url_parts['query'], $url_arguments);

$full_url = $config['base_url'].$url; // Url with the query on it.
$base_url = $config['base_url'].$url_parts['path']; // Url without the query.

if (!dbglog(" > ORIGINAL: ".$full_url)) { die("Huh?"); }

// Replace characters
foreach($specialCharacters as $lookup => $replace) {
    $full_url = str_replace($lookup,$replace,$full_url);
}

if (!dbglog(" > REPLACED: ".$full_url)) { die("Huh?"); }

/**
* Code below from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916539/simplest-php-example-retrieving-user-timeline-with-twitter-api-version-1-1 by Rivers 
* with a few modfications by Mike Rogers to support variables in the URL nicely
*/

function buildBaseString($baseURI, $method, $params) {
    $r = array();
    ksort($params);
    foreach($params as $key=>$value){
    $r[] = "$key=" . rawurlencode($value);
    }
    return $method."&" . rawurlencode($baseURI) . '&' . rawurlencode(implode('&', $r));
}

function buildAuthorizationHeader($oauth) {
    $r = 'Authorization: OAuth ';
    $values = array();
    foreach($oauth as $key=>$value)
    $values[] = "$key=\"" . rawurlencode($value) . "\"";
    $r .= implode(', ', $values);
    return $r;
}

// Set up the oauth Authorization array
$oauth = array(
    'oauth_consumer_key' => $config['consumer_key'],
    'oauth_nonce' => time(),
    'oauth_signature_method' => 'HMAC-SHA1',
    'oauth_token' => $config['oauth_access_token'],
    'oauth_timestamp' => time(),
    'oauth_version' => '1.0'
);

$base_info = buildBaseString($base_url, 'GET', array_merge($oauth, $url_arguments));
$composite_key = rawurlencode($config['consumer_secret']) . '&' . rawurlencode($config['oauth_access_token_secret']);
$oauth_signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $base_info, $composite_key, true));
$oauth['oauth_signature'] = $oauth_signature;

// Make Requests
$header = array(
    buildAuthorizationHeader($oauth), 
    'Expect:'
);
$options = array(
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $header,
    //CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postfields,
    CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
    CURLOPT_URL => $full_url,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false
);

try {
    $feed = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($feed, $options);
    $result = curl_exec($feed);
    $info = curl_getinfo($feed);
    curl_close($feed);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    die("Error: ".$e);
}

// Send suitable headers to the end user.
if(isset($info['content_type']) && isset($info['size_download'])){
    header('Content-Type: '.$info['content_type']);
    header('Content-Length: '.$info['size_download']);

}

echo($result);
?>
```

Comment: Hmm I found this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17164587/get-search-results-without-user-authentication

It looks like this is a twitter-issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this same issue when building [this library](https://github.com/J7mbo/twitter-api-php).

[This commit](https://github.com/J7mbo/twitter-api-php/commit/5c2b97e402d04114ca3be6a793eebcd8521d76a5) specifically might yield some more information.

The issue that you have basically is that you are URL encoding incorrectly - maybe even twice. If you view the code from the source above (it's very similar, seems like it's been modified there), then it'll work exactly as you wanted.

**TLDR:** Use the above single file instead, or just copy/paste the code out of it. It's pretty much what you want.

As OP found: he also tried replacing it with `%2523` (where `%25` = `%`). It's still advisable to check out the above library.

Comment: Thanks will give it a try. in the meantime I got it to work with %2523 (%25 is url-encoding for '%') and now it works. The weird thing is that %40 works just like that, no need to %2540 it..

Comment: I'll add your code to my answer so other users can find it. @REJH If you think the answer in it's current form is good enough, could you 'tick' it? Cheers.

Comment: Jep your answer seems to work also. I will probably switch to that in the future, looks cleaner :)